# Configurable items in related and upsell areas

Tags: configurable-product, up-sells, related-products, registry

I have been following a tutorial - http://catgento.com/2012/02/09/adding-configurable-product-options-to-category-list-in-magento/ - to add configurable products dropdowns to the configurable products on different pages. 
I have successfully added a block of configurable products that are set as new on the home page.

My issue is when I try and add configurable products to the related products and upsell products in a single product page then one of the areas (upsell or related products) doesn't show up. Within the tutorial it mentions about using the registry to unset and set the product object and I think this is where my problem lies.
 Can anyone see any way around this?